# How to add user-defined network-modes in GitHub Action Workflow

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Unable to add `--net=host`, gh-action complains cannot attach user-defined network-modes

I am using service container approach to add `--net=host` option while bringing up container in GitHub Action but it doesn't help.

Error faced :

```
docker: conflicting options: cannot attach both user-defined and non-user-defined network-modes.
```

Here's snippet

```
runs-on: [ self-hosted, build_server ]
    services:
      host_service:
        image: <>
        options: --net=host
    needs : [ container-version ]
    steps:`
```

GH-Action starts container like this

```
--label 621794 --network github_network_13cec713344a4fe2b68c7352ca2e9893 --network-alias host_service --net=host
```

How to resolve this

Comment: Facing the same issue
Any fix ?

Comment: GH Action does not support --net=host instead do volume mount -v /sys:sys/ro